# Coldfusion - Dumping out two different components in a Structure/Array

Tags: coldfusion

I have found a strange bug in Coldfusion when adding two different components into some form of data structure and dumping them out.

For the purpose of this question I have simplified my code. I have Component A and Component B, both have one property, one constructor, and one function.

I create an instance of A, and an instance of B. When I dump the instances out separately I see the correct metadata.

However when I add the two instances to a data structure (Component B in first slot, A in second), it appears as if the methods from the instance in slot 1 are duplicated in the instance in slot 2, even though they are different objects. i.e. I see CompBFunction, GetCompBProp, SetCompBProp listed as methods for Comp A. The properties however look correct.

It is worth mentioning, that I cannot call the methods for Comp B on Comp A - This seems to be a display issue. I tried calling CompBFunction on my object 'a' and it failed as expected.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. I understand it's not a huge issue - but it can be rather misleading to see these methods here when they don't exist. There are many instances in my code where I would want to build up a Data Structure of mixed components.

Apologies if this question has been asked before - I searched high and low, but could not find any info on it. I am using CF9.

Here is my example code:-

Component A

```
component name="CompA" output="false" cache="false" accessors="true" {
    property name="CompAprop" type="Numeric" getter="true" setter="true";

    public CompA function init() output="false" {
        return this;
    }

    public String function CompAFunction() output="false" {
    return "All";
    }
}
```

Component B

```
component name="CompB" output="false" cache="false" accessors="true" {
    property name="CompBprop" type="Numeric" getter="true" setter="true";

    public CompB function init() output="false" {
        return this;
    }

    public String function CompBFunction() output="false" {
    return "All";
    }
}
```

index.cfm

```
<cfset a = new CompA() />
<cfset b = new CompB() />

<cfset test = ArrayNew(1) />
<cfset test[1] = b />
<cfset test[2] = a />

<cfdump var="#test#" /> <!--- METHODS FOR B APPEAR IN METADATA FOR A --->
<cfdump var="#test[1]#" /> <!--- METADATA CORRECT --->
<cfdump var="#test[2]#" /> <!--- METADATA CORRECT --->
<cfabort />
```

Images

[image: Direct Dump]

[image: Dump in Data Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me on CF 9.0.1 (update: *and* on CF10), and I have never encountered anything like the problem you're describing in the past. People would have raised this as a bug if it was an actual problem with ColdFusion, because it'd crop up fairly frequently, I reckon.

You *have* noticed that you're putting CompB into the array at index 1, and CompA into element 2, yeah? This conflicts with what you say in your question "However when I add the two instances to a data structure (Component A in first slot, B in second),". So one would expect them to be the "wrong" way round?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer - Yeah my code shows it the wrong way around to what my question stated. I was testing to see if it did the same the other way around. If I put CompA in slot one and CompB in slot 2, CompA's functions appear in slot 2 also. Could possibly be an issue with my version of CF if it's working OK for you - I'll try a different version.

Comment: So basically the first dump showed the same output whichever way you had them round? Or were they opposite expectations either way?

Comment: Opposite either way - If A is in slot 1, B has A's methods. If B is in slot 1, A has B's methods. Must be a problem with the core Coldfusion code for cfdump?? I checked the exact version number for my CF - It's 9,0,0,251028 Developer. I'll try and test the code on the same version as yourself, or even better, CF10. Thanks again

Comment: Images added above now I have 10 rep :-)

Comment: I can confirm that this problem does not occur on CF10 - It must have been fixed between 9.0.0 and 9.0.1. Thanks for your help, Adam.